# Given a vector, is the probability of sampling an orthogonal vector zero?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality, random

Given a unit vector $u\in \mathbb R^n$, take $v$ to be sampled uniformly at random from the unit sphere centered at $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Is the probability of $u$ and $v$ being orthogonal equal to zero?

I am inclined to say yes, because the measure of a hyperplane is zero. Is this sufficient (and correct)?

Comment: You cannot have an uniform random distrubition on $\mathbb R^n$, because it has infinite volume.

Comment: But you can sample a vector with norm 1 uniformly. For the sake of this question, this should be enough. And then the answer is yes.

Comment: Perhaps select a direction uniformly from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and select its length from some other distribution (with support on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$)...

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the probabily will be $0$. The uniform probability distrubution means that we the probability distribution is defined by the Lebesgue measure inherited by $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ from $\mathbb R^n$. For any measurable $A \subset \mathbb S^{n-1}$ is given by $$P(A) = \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(\mathbb S^{n-1})} $$
If $\mu(A)=0$ (like in the case of the great circle formed by vectors $v \perp u$), then also $P(A)=0$.